# rails 4 extend the build method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to extend the build method or create another method which pre-populates the child model with attributes from the parent automatically.

I'm presently doing this in the controller each time...

```
@event_log = @event.event_logs.build(
  place_id: @event.place_id, quiz_master_id: @event.quiz_master_id,
  start_at: Chronic.parse("#{params[:start_at]} #{@event.start_time}")
  )
```

I would like to move this logic into the model:

```
  def self.auto_build
    build(place_id: event.place_id, .....)
  end
```

But i get an error.. `undefined method event`

I'm not sure how to either override build for this model only or to create a similar method:

```
# File 'activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb', line 11

def self.build(model, name, options)
  new(model, name, options).build
end
```

Comment: Do you want to override the deafult  `build` method provided by Rails?

Comment: This error means that your `event_log` object doesn't have `event` object associated to it.

Comment: Yup, that would be my preference for this model, unless there's some reason not to.

Comment: But when you call `event` in your `event_log` model, it simply doesn't know what `event` is.

Comment: Yeah, i get that, but i'm not sure how to pass in the model other than event.event_logs.auto_build(model)...

Comment: So you only `has_many :event_logs` in the Event model? If you would add `belongs_to :event` in your EventLog model, everything would get much easier, as there would be no problem with accessing the event object.

Comment: would you be ok with a custom build method placed in the `event` class?

Comment: I want to extend the build method (or create a similar one) to automatically add 2-3 other fields from the parent... normal functionality from has_many belongs_to work 100% fine.

Comment: re: custom build method.. sure.  I guess I just assumed it would go in the child model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use association extension for that:

```
has_many :event_logs do
  def build(*args)
    event_log = super
    # do with event_log object whatever you want here
    # you can access parent object with proxy_association.owner
    event_log
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in the child model, but reading from your controller you could do this in the parent model you could do:

```
def build_event_log
  event_logs.build(
    place_id: place_id, 
    quiz_master_id: quiz_master_id
    ...
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try some like this :

To create a new method or to override the default build method, create a module and place it in config/initailzers,

For Ex :

```
# config/initializers/active_relation_helper.rb

module ActiveRelationHelper

  def build(attribute_hash = {})
    # Your content
  end

  ActiveRecord::Relation.send(:include, ActiveRelationHelper)
end
```